# How do i build a program with QTCreator, .pro file?

Tags: application-development, qt

im sort of new to Linux and i'd like some advice on how to build CalcProgrammer on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

(https://github.com/CalcProgrammer1/KeyboardVisualizer)

It is an LED keyboard audio visualizer which works with some Razer Chroma devices.

The way it says to build it is this:

-To build this project in Linux, install QT Creator and libopenal-dev, libhidapi-dev and open/build the .pro file.

I have QT Creator, i know how to install libopenal-dev and libhidapi-dev through terminal, i just need tips on how to build the .pro file for CalcProgrammer.

Answer (score 0):

At first we need to install development packages:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential qt4-dev-tools libopenal-dev \
qt4-default libhidapi-dev
```

Then clone git repository and compile the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/CalcProgrammer1/KeyboardVisualizer
cd KeyboardVisualizer
qmake-qt4
make
```

But after running the last command I get error messages on clean Ubuntu 16.04 LTS amd64.
I reported [bug 226 to official GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/CalcProgrammer1/KeyboardVisualizer/issues/226).

Comment: Thanks for that, i just tried it, and i got around 5 errors. Is that the same for you? This is the last error shown: 'Makefile:263: recipe for target 'LEDStrip.o' failed
make: *** [LEDStrip.o] Error 1'.  Hopefully someone can figure this out, i miss the keyboard visualisations i had on Windows